# Regexp: check if repeated group contains a letter at least once

Tags: regex, url-validation

I am learning regular expressions and have a task to make an expression to validate URLs (I have a specific list of URLs that must validate and must fail). Here is what I currently have

```
^((https?:\/\/)(?=.*[A-Za-z]+.*)(([A-Za-z0-9]+\-*[A-Za-z0-9]+|[A-Za-z0-9])\.){1,}([A-Za-z]+)\/?$)
```

Among all other URLs, these URLs must validate:

```
http://1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa
http://0test.com/
```

However these must fail:

```
http://1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234.com
http://0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.com
```

They must fail because they have no letters in the domain name (only in the top level domain name), and I don't understand how to exclude them.

I have added a positive lookahead:

```
(?=.*[A-Za-z]+.*)
```

I was hoping that it will only check the following repeated group:

```
(([A-Za-z0-9]+\-*[A-Za-z0-9]+|[A-Za-z0-9])\.){1,}
```

but it checks the the whole expression until the end, i.e. it checks in the top level domain name too. How do I solve this?

Comment: Just curious, this `[A-z]` was not a typo ?

Comment: That was actually my mistake that I didn't notice due to samples not containing any much different TLDs. Thanks for pointing it out, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but, as you said, you dont want the lookahead to account for the top level domain name. So include a copy of that match in your look ahead:

```
(?=.*[A-Za-z]+.*\.([A-Za-z]+)$\/?)
                 ^-------- will match the top level domain
                          ^ will ensure its the last part of the domain
```

I also changed your `A-z` to `A-Za-z` (wasn't sure if typo but reminder that `A-z` matches more than just letters)

EDIT: look behind doesnt work because it doesn't allow for variable sized matching. Added the `\/?` for possible `/` ending

Comment: I am using https://regex101.com/ to test the expressions. The first solution (almost) worked, thanks! I only had to add the `\/?` before the `$` (to match the URLs with the slash at the end). Now it seems pretty obvious.

As for the lookbehind, it didn't work. Did you make a typo there? Lookbehinds start with `(?<=` for me. And the regex101 site tells me that _Lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed_

Comment: oh yeah thats my bad, I accidentally deleted the `?` And I forgot about that little hitch, lookbehinds probably wouldnt work then

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off with this assertion
`(?=.*[A-Za-z]+.*\.[A-Za-z]+/?$)`

Using that and some refactoring, this raw regex validates and invalidates
the correct items in your sample.

`^(https?://)(?=.*[A-Za-z]+.*\.[A-Za-z]+/?$)((?:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-+[A-Za-z0-9]+)?\.)+)([A-Za-z]+)/?$`

[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 ^ 
 ( https?:// )                 # (1)
 (?= .* [A-Za-z]+ .* \. [A-Za-z]+ /? $ )
 (                             # (2 start)
      (?:
           [A-Za-z0-9]+ 
           (?:
                -+
                [A-Za-z0-9]+ 
           )?
           \.
      )+
 )                             # (2 end)
 ( [A-Za-z]+ )                 # (3)
 /?
 $
```

Comment: Thanks for that. You don't escape slashes with backslashes tho, is that okay in some engines? Doesn't work on https://regex101.com/ that I am using. Also in your refactored version i find `|[A-Za-z0-9]` being useless (because you were smart enough to add `?` to allow domains without hyphens). And also just I didn't bother with non-capturing groups.

Comment: @Ubeogesh - True about that  `|[A-Za-z0-9]` being useless, I modified the answer. However, `Doesn't work on regex101.com` is not true. The fallacy of sites like that with that type of input scheme is some people believe the forward slash is a special regex metacharacter that needs to be escaped. Which it isn't and doesn't need to be. That's why answers here give _raw_ regex's, not delimited ones. Their scheme is to show a fixed delimiter so you can see the **modifiers**, has nothing to do with delimiters. `/`your regex here`/modifiers` is not correct.

Comment: For example, `~^(https?://)(?=.*[A-Za-z]+.*\.[A-Za-z]+/?$)((?:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-+[A-Za-z0-9]+)?\.)+)([A-Za-z]+)/?$~m` is a proper regex, delimited with `~`.